# 24H format converts for a second in 12H format when i click 12H button

Tags: jquery

I have two buttons one to convert to 24h time and one to convert to 12h time. When I click the 12h button it converts for a second in 12h format and changes back to 24h. for example if its 13:00 it converts to 1:00pm for a sec and changes back to 13:00. How can i make it stay as 1:00pm and only change when I click the 24h button?

```js
function clock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var $hour = date.getHours();
  var $minutes = date.getMinutes();

  //Add 0 if hour and minutes are before 10//

  if ($hour < 10) $hour = "0" + $hour;
  if ($minutes < 10) $minutes = "0" + $minutes;

  $("#hour").html($hour);
  $("#minutes").html($minutes);

  //Convert to 12H//
  $("#twelveHourTime").on("click", function() {
    $("#ampm").html("AM");

    if ($hour >= 12) {
      $("#hour").html($hour - 12);
      $("#ampm").html("PM");
    }
  });

  //Convert to 24H//
  $("#twentyFourHourTime").on("click", function() {
    $("#hour").html($hour);
    $("#minutes").html($minutes);
    $("#ampm").html(" ");
  });

};

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval('clock()', 1000);
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="clock">
    <span id="hour"></span>
    <span id="seconds">:</span>
    <span id="minutes"></span>
    <span id="ampm"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <button id="twentyFourHourTime">24H</button>
    <button id="twelveHourTime">12H</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont want the click handlers to be in clock function (this way they get applied each second, its enough to apply them once)

I would use a variable to store the decision and in the click-handlers you just set the var according

```js
var am_pm = false;

function clock() {
  var date = new Date();
  var $hour = date.getHours();
  var $minutes = date.getMinutes();

  //Add 0 if hour and minutes are before 10//

  if ($hour < 10) $hour = "0" + $hour;
  if ($minutes < 10) $minutes = "0" + $minutes;

  // if 12h is true
  if(am_pm){
    $("#ampm").html("AM");
    if($hour >= 12){
      $hour = $hour - 12;
      $("#ampm").html("PM");
    }
  }else{
    $("#ampm").html(" ");
  }

  $("#hour").html($hour);
  $("#minutes").html($minutes);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#twelveHourTime").on("click", function() {
    am_pm = true;    
  });
  $("#twentyFourHourTime").on("click", function() {
    am_pm = false
  });
  setInterval('clock()', 1000);
});
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="clock">
    <span id="hour"></span>
    <span id="seconds">:</span>
    <span id="minutes"></span>
    <span id="ampm"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="btn">
    <button id="twentyFourHourTime">24H</button>
    <button id="twelveHourTime">12H</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to save the stage in an external variable and check every time you call clock() what format is needed.
By the way: $ as a variable prefix is not common in javascript as it is in PHP.

```
var twelfHourMode = false;

function clock() 
{
  var date = new Date();
  var hour = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();

  //Add 0 if hour and minutes are before 10//

  if (hour < 10) hour = "0" + hour;
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;

  $("#hour").html(hour);
  $("#minutes").html(minutes);
  $("#ampm").html("");
  if(twelfHourMode)
  {
      $("#ampm").html("AM");
      if ($hour >= 12)
      {
          $("#hour").html(hour - 12);
          $("#ampm").html("PM");
      }
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    //Convert to 12H//
    $("#twelveHourTime").on("click", function() 
    {
         twelfHourMode = true;
         clock();
    });

    //Convert to 24H//
    $("#twentyFourHourTime").on("click", function() 
    {
         twelfHourMode = false;
         clock();
    });

    setInterval('clock('+')', 1000);
});
```